# problem with upgrade - "packages have been kept back"

Tags: upgrade

one package `libgbm1` is not upgraded I dont know why...

```
sudo apt-get upgrade
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
The following packages have been kept back:
  libgbm1
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 1 not upgraded.
```

why is this package is not upgraded?